# Can I authorize a user to only perform the 'Manage Data' Operation, and none of the other Operations

Tags: stellar-sdk

**Can I authorize a user to ***only*** perform the 'Manage Data' Operation, and none of the other Operations listed here:**
https://developers.stellar.org/docs/start/list-of-operations/

I noticed that the Threshold for the 'Manage Data' operation is 'Medium'. Does that mean that they would be able to perform all the other Operations with a Threshold of Medium or Low, including "Payment"?

Is there a workaround for this problem? I only want additional signers to be able to add Data Entries, and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to restrict a signer so that it can only perform Manage Data operations. If a signer's weight meets the Medium threshold it can do all operations requiring a Medium or Low threshold.

https://developers.stellar.org/docs/glossary/multisig/#thresholds